# Getting stack traces for all threads of a concurrent access:

Tags: java, debugging, concurrentmodification

We seem to have a concurrent access to a method in our code. A workaround would be to synchronize that method. But that would not fix the root cause: there should be no such concurrent access in the first place.

How to get the stack traces of all threads that access this method, but only in the case there is a concurrent access?

Another option would be detecting that the synchronization would block - before it actually blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Reentrant lock to suit the purpose. Here is the sample code:

```
private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

      public void sampleLock() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
          Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "interrupted");
        }
        lock.unlock();
      }
```

If any other method wants to access `sampleLock()` method then `lock.isLocked()` will tell if it is used by any other thread.
Please go through the Oracle documentation for the same. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html

Comment: no idea how this answers the question, since now every thread accessing this method has to do a `lock.isLocked` to know whatever some thread is holding the lock

Comment: Well, the code piece is a little misleading, indeed. Replacing the `try-catch / sleep` part with some meta code, like `<your code>` would improve it.  But the answer pointed me to `ReentrantLock`. With that, writing some small code piece that logged the stack traces in case of concurrent access was quite simple

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options for you here.

The basic code is

```
    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    if(!lock.tryLock()) {
        Map<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> threads = Thread.getAllStackTraces();
    }
    try {
        ///your code
    }
    finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
```

So if you can attach a debugger to your application, you can set the breakpoint to the

```
Map<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> threads = Thread.getAllStackTraces();
```

line, which will pause all threads. Then you can see all the threads and their stack traces in that map

If you cannot attach a debugger, then simply iterate over that map and get all stack traces.

Another way without using a lock can be this:

```
private Set<Thread> threads = new HashSet<>();

public void yourMethodInQuestion() {
    threads.add(Thread.currentThread());
    if( threads.size() >= 2 ) {
        //iterate and get all the threads information
    }
    ....
}
```

I hope that helps.

*Michael, 
Author of the **Java Multithreading, Concurrency and Performance Optimization** course*

https://www.udemy.com/java-multithreading-concurrency-performance-optimization/?couponCode=CONCURRENCY

Comment: Certainly a valid answer, but not in my case. I'm working with a legacy system, running on a remote server. No debugger access available, usually. So I have to log stuff I need. The accepted points to some way to do that

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, if you CANNOT attach a debugger, you still have all the information in that map, you can iterate and log it, print it out. Right away or after a few iterations, whatever you prefer